# I am using react-dnd in react version 16.0.1, I cant upgrade the react version but react-dnd is not working in this version

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am getting this error

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' in 'C:\Micromerger\realStockExchange\node_modules\react-dnd\dist\core'
Did you mean 'jsx-runtime.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'react/jsx-runtime' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.

Comment: I think this question is helpful pls check [link](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/3137)

Comment: let me check thanks